# Android SQLite trigger troubles

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I'm relatively new to SQL/SQLite and I'm trying to set up a trigger in my database.  Basically, there is one table containing the names and ids of people and the other table contains entries for those people.  Here is the schema of my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE people(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name STRING NOT NULL,
 amount_people INTEGER);
```

```
 CREATE TABLE entries (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    user INTEGER NOT NULL, date STRING NOT NULL, 
      title STRING NOT NULL, amount_entry INTEGER NOT NULL,
    notes STRING, FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES people (_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

I would like to build a trigger that updates the balance for the user in the people table each time a new entry is created for that user in the entries table.  This seems like it should be easy, but I've spent the last 2 hours trying to achieve this with no success.

Here is my wrong version of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_balance AFTER INSERT ON entries 
BEGIN
UPDATE people SET amount_people = amount_people + (amount_entry FROM entries) 
   WHERE _id = (user FROM entries);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested...

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_balance AFTER INSERT ON entries 
BEGIN
UPDATE people SET amount_people = amount_people + new.amount_entry 
   WHERE _id = new.user;
END;
```

Comment: Ah that worked and it's exactly what I was trying to achieve!  In some of my attempts at the trigger, I was prefixing amount_people with old and new, I think that's where I went wrong.  Thanks for the response!